# Can't Resolve R ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have been trying for hours to figure out why I am getting this errr

R cannot be resolved to a variable

I am using the newest version of ABS (4.2) which I have added to eclipse as a project.  I then added the project as a library to my project.  Both manifests have:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

This is the line throwing the error:

```
    String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
```

I have tried cleaning all projects, and restarting eclipse but nothing is working.  My Activity is a SherlockActivity.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `R` is one of the most annoying things to deal with in android. Does it even get generated?

Comment: Looks like I am getting an R.Java under my applications package name, as well as another R.java under com.actionbarsherlock

Comment: On a side note if I am using ABS do I still need to add the android-support library to my project

Comment: Just tried deleting project and re-importing from a backup but same problem.

Comment: I assume you added the appropriate `import` statement?

Comment: @Nath5 you shouldn't have to, ABS imports the support library. Back to your R.java note, I have an R for my ABS library and another R for my main project. I would suggest explictly importing com.yourpackage.R to see if that works, although by default this **isn't** needed.

Comment: It appears that importing the com.nathan.myproject R.java has resolved the error however I would like to know why I was getting the error in the first place.  I thought I read somewhere that I should not directly import R

Comment: Your eclipse is being odd. Normally you do not import R. Maybe your project's build path is not correctly configured.

Comment: You should never import R. It will make the errors disappear, but you've just made the problem worse! Can you give more details on the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with all the R, you have to delete the java-support library4 in the library from ActionBarSherlock and then Clean the project

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the root cause but including the R.java under my applications package name fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the java support library4, but did not work. So I did a Maven - Update Project, and it's done.